# Laravel and Controllers Using Artisan Template 5.2

Tags: controller, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am putting through the command

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController
```

It create the `Controller`, however inside the `controller` it does not have the template for:

`show` `index` `edit` etc etc.

The only reason why I think it should have that basic layout is from the tutorial I am watching to learn laravel. I have installed it on a completely different machine and the thing. I have the controller, but none of the:

`show`
`index`
`edit`

What am I doing wrong? Or is it Laravel?

Comment: what do you mean by does not contains show, index, edit etc ? can you add up some sample code, So I can have a look

Comment: Hi Quazi. Paranoid below got the answer with adding the --resource to the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel 5.2 you should use `--resource`
Try this

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
```

Comment: Hi Paranoid.. that worked perfectly. Why is there the sudden addition of --resource to the end?

Answer (score 0):

please refer the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

In Laravel 5.1 and below, the command you were using, used to work. But with 5.2 it got changed.

Best way to know is to use the Artisan Command help.

```
php artisan help make:controller
```